# How to improve performance of coincidence filtering of a time-series?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, numpy, time-series

I'm working on instationary experimental data from fluid dynamics. We have measured data on three channels, so the samples are not directly coincident (measured at the same time). I want to filter them with a window scheme to get coincident samples and disgard all others.

Unfortunately, I cannot upload the original data set due to restrictions of the company. But I tried to set up a minimal example, which generates a similiar (smaller) dataset. The original dataset consists of 500000 values per channel, each noted with an arrival time. The coincidence is checked with these time stamps.

Just now, I loop over each sample from the first channel and look at the time differences to the other channels. If it is smaller than the specified window width, the index is saved. Probably it would be a little bit faster if I specifiy an intervall in which to check for the differences (like 100 or 1000 samples in the neighborhood). But the datarate between the channels can differ significantly, so it is not implemented yet. I prefer to get rid of looping over each sample - if possible.

```
def filterCoincidence(df, window = 50e-6):
        '''
        Filters the dataset with arbitrary different data rates on different channels to coincident samples.
        The coincidence is checked with regard to a time window specified as argument.
        '''
        AT_cols = [col for col in df.columns if 'AT' in col]
        if len(AT_cols) == 1:
            print('only one group available')
            return
        used_ix = np.zeros( (df.shape[0], len(AT_cols)))
        used_ix.fill(np.nan)
        for ix, sample in enumerate(df[AT_cols[0]]):
            used_ix[ix, 0] = ix
            test_ix = np.zeros(2)
            for ii, AT_col in enumerate(AT_cols[1:]):
                diff = np.abs(df[AT_col] - sample)
                index = diff[diff <= window].sort_values().index.values
                if len(index) == 0:
                    test_ix[ii] = None
                    continue
                test_ix[ii] = [ix_use if (ix_use not in used_ix[:, ii+1] or ix == 0) else None for ix_use in index][0]
            if not np.any(np.isnan(test_ix)):
                used_ix[ix, 1:] = test_ix
            else:
                used_ix[ix, 1:] = [None, None]
        used_ix = used_ix[~np.isnan(used_ix).any(axis=1)]
        print(used_ix.shape)
        return

no_points = 10000
no_groups = 3
meas_duration = 60
df = pd.DataFrame(np.transpose([np.sort(np.random.rand(no_points)*meas_duration) for _ in range(no_groups)]), columns=['AT {}'.format(i) for i in range(no_groups)])
filterCoincidence(df, window=1e-3)
```

Is there a module already implemented, which can do this sort of filtering? However, it would be awesome if you can give me some hints to increase the performance of the code.

Comment: Is `df` the *test* data? It has three columns, are those time *marks*? Does the actual DataFrame contain more columns with the measurement data for each of those *timestamps*?

Comment: Are the samples periodic but offset between the three channels? Or are the samples aperiodic? For every sample in `AT 0` is there just one sample in the other columns that is considered *coincident*?

Comment: Yes exactly. The data is stored in a pandas dataframe `df`. Per group exists at least 3 columns, but only the arrival time (AT) of the particles matter for coincidence. The arrival time is measured in seconds and is shifted regarding the first sample, so ist starts at 0 and then always has a timestamp (in seconds), when the measurement is triggered.

Comment: The measurement procedure cannot guarantee equidistant sampling. So each group is less or more independent from each other (physically of course not, we measure 3 velocity components but want to know the velocity at one time --> coincidence is required). So there is no constant offset and no knowledge how many or even if samples are coincident to each other. But i just need to find samples, which match to each other. so from 10000 samples i will get lets say 1000, who are coincident and can be considered as measured at the same time.

Comment: Does your function produce the correct result? Is its result `used_ix`?

Comment: `used_ix` is an array, which stores the indices of the coincident samples. This means for example `used_ix[10,:] = [10, 7, 8]`. So the 10th coincident sample can be found in the dataframe at the index 10 for the first group, 7 for the second and 9 for the last. And I hope the window filtering is correct, I tested it once and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Just to update this thread if somebody else have a similar problem. I think after several code revisions, I have found a proper solution to this.

```py
def filterCoincidence(self, AT1, AT2, AT3, window = 0.05e-3):
    '''
    Filters the dataset with arbitrary different data rates on different channels to coincident samples.
    The coincidence is checked with regard to a time window specified as argument.

    - arguments:
        - three times series AT1, AT2 and AT3 (arrival times of particles in my case)
        - window size (50 microseconds as default setting)

    - output: indices of combined samples
    '''

    start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    AT_list = [AT1, AT2, AT3]

    # take the shortest period of time
    min_EndArrival = np.max(AT_list)
    max_BeginArrival = np.min(AT_list)
    for i, col in enumerate(AT_list):
        min_EndArrival = min(min_EndArrival, np.max(col))
        max_BeginArrival = max(max_BeginArrival, np.min(col))
    for i, col in enumerate(AT_list):
        AT_list[i] = np.delete(AT_list[i], np.where((col < max_BeginArrival - window) | (col > min_EndArrival + window)))

    # get channel with lowest datarate
    num_points = np.zeros(len(AT_list))
    datarate = np.zeros(len(AT_list))

    for i, AT in enumerate(AT_list):
        num_points[i] = AT.shape[0]
        datarate[i] = num_points[i] / (AT[-1]-AT[0])
    used_ref = np.argmin(datarate)

    # process coincidence
    AT_ref_val = AT_list[used_ref]
    AT_list = list(np.delete(AT_list, used_ref))
    overview = np.zeros( (AT_ref_val.shape[0], 3), dtype=int)
    overview[:,0] = np.arange(AT_ref_val.shape[0], dtype=int)
    borders = np.empty(2, dtype=object)
    max_diff = np.zeros(2, dtype=int)
    for i, AT in enumerate(AT_list):
        neighbors_lower = np.searchsorted(AT, AT_ref_val - window, side='left')
        neighbors_upper = np.searchsorted(AT, AT_ref_val + window, side='left')
        borders[i] = np.transpose([neighbors_lower, neighbors_upper])
        coinc_ix = np.where(np.diff(borders[i], axis=1).flatten() != 0)[0]
        max_diff[i] = np.max(np.diff(borders[i], axis=1))
        overview[coinc_ix, i+1] = 1
    use_ix = np.where(~np.any(overview==0, axis=1))
    borders[0] = borders[0][use_ix]
    borders[1] = borders[1][use_ix]
    overview = overview[use_ix]

    # create all possible combinations refer to the reference
    combinations = np.prod(max_diff)
    test = np.empty((overview.shape[0]*combinations, 3), dtype=object)
    for i, [ref_ix, at1, at2] in enumerate(zip(overview[:, 0], borders[0], borders[1])):
        test[i * combinations:i * combinations + combinations, 0] = ref_ix
        at1 = np.arange(at1[0], at1[1])
        at2 = np.arange(at2[0], at2[1])
        test[i*combinations:i*combinations+at1.shape[0]*at2.shape[0],1:] = np.asarray(list(itertools.product(at1, at2)))
    test = test[~np.any(pd.isnull(test), axis=1)]

    # check distances
    ix_ref = test[:,0]
    test = test[:,1:]
    test = np.insert(test, used_ref, ix_ref, axis=1)
    test = test.astype(int)

    AT_list.insert(used_ref, AT_ref_val)
    AT_mat = np.zeros(test.shape)
    for i, AT in enumerate(AT_list):
        AT_mat[:,i] = AT[test[:,i]]

    distances = np.zeros( (test.shape[0], len(list(itertools.combinations(range(3), 2)))))
    for i, AT in enumerate(itertools.combinations(range(3), 2)):
        distances[:,i] = np.abs(AT_mat[:,AT[0]]-AT_mat[:,AT[1]])
    ix = np.where(np.all(distances <= window, axis=1))[0]
    test = test[ix,:]
    distances = distances[ix,:]

    # check duplicates
    # use sum of differences as similarity factor
    dist_sum = np.max(distances, axis=1)
    unique_sorted = np.argsort([np.unique(test[:,i]).shape[0] for i in range(test.shape[1])])[::-1]
    test = np.hstack([test, dist_sum.reshape(-1, 1)])
    test = test[test[:,-1].argsort()]
    for j in unique_sorted:
        _, ix = np.unique(test[:,j], return_index=True)
        test = test[ix, :]
    test = test[:,:3]
    test = test[test[:,used_ref].argsort()]
    # check that all values are after each other
    ix = np.where(np.any(np.diff(test, axis=0) > 0, axis=1))[0]
    ix = np.append(ix, test.shape[0]-1)
    test = test[ix,:]
    print('{} coincident samples obtained in {}.'.format(test.shape[0], datetime.datetime.now()-start_time))
    return test
```

I'm certain that there is a better solution, but for me it works now. And I know, the variable names should definitely be chosen with more clarity (e.g. `test`), but I will clean up my code at the end of my master thesis... perhaps :-)